Cite author name with 'et al.' only for 3 or more authors
I give another try to solve this
Cite author with Eurographics/CGF template
using this
Customize `\citeauthor*` to show full author name but UpperCase only the first letter
I can define \citet as the suggested \citeauthornsc for lower case, but then I need to decide if to add a star * or not, depending on the number of authors. Is there away to automate this, like in natbib, where it would use 'and' for two authors and 'et al.' for more automatically?
Meaning, define a new \citet command that would call \citeauthornsc if there are up to 2 authors and \citeauthornsc* otherwise.

For you convenience, I'm pasting the answer from the second link, which pertains to this questions:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthornsc}
  {\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{####1}%
   \boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citeauthornsc}
  {\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{####1}%
   \boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames[][1-1]{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}
Standard small caps:
\citeauthor{wilde}
our new command:
\citeauthornsc{wilde}
small caps again:
\citeauthor{wilde}
\autocite{wilde}
\end{document}

Moreover, this is an updated EG latex template in case you have a more elegant solution to the problem in my first link:
https://www.eg.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/egPublStyle-cgf.zip
which I copied from
https://www.eg.org/wp/eurographics-publications/guidelines/

It's accomplished somehow in
\usepackage[datamodel=acmdatamodel,style=acmauthoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}


The links are greatly appreciated, but please post a complete compilable example here, too.

biblatex has min/maxcitenames options, which can override the min/maxnames settings in EG.bbx:
\documentclass{egpubl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=EG,citestyle=alphabetic,mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthornsc}
  {\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{####1}%
   \boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\citet}[1]{\citeauthornsc{#1}~\cite{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{kim07,
  title={Simulation of bubbles in foam with the volume control method},
  author={Kim, Byungmoon and Liu, Yingjie and Llamas, Ignacio and Jiao, Xiangmin and Rossignac, Jarek},
  journal={ACM Transactions on Graphics},
  volume={26},
  number={3},
  pages={98--es},
  year={2007},
}

@inproceedings{stam99,
  title={Stable fluids},
  author={Stam, Jos},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 26th annual conference on Computer graphics and interactive techniques},
  pages={121--128},
  year={1999}
}

@article{foster96,
  title={Realistic animation of liquids},
  author={Foster, Nick and Metaxas, Dimitri},
  journal={Graphical models and image processing},
  volume={58},
  number={5},
  pages={471--483},
  year={1996},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\citet{kim07}

\citet{foster96}

\citet{stam99}

\printbibliography
\end{document}

